# Logo size on a header

Tags: html, css, header

I need help with my code.I am trying to make a website with a sticky header.However,the buttons on the page gets over the body part.
This is the codepen page of my website: [Click here](http://codepen.io/terlan/full/xEZkaZ/)

And here is my code:

```
<header style="position:fixed"class="container-fluid header a">

<div class="row">
 <a href="#top"><img src="http://hguochen.com/static/img/tech/css3.png"style="max-width:80px"class="img-responsive"></a>
<div class="col-xs-6">

  <a href="#scr"><button class="btn btn-primary">ABOUT</button></a>
  <a href="#scr"><button class="btn btn-primary">PORTFOLIO</button></a>
  <a href="#scr"><button class="btn btn-primary">CONTACT</button></a>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</header>
```

Comment: thats because headers heigth: 13%

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply an offset to your page-contents equal to (or greater than) the height of the fixed header element; for example --

```
<header style="position:fixed; top: 0; height: 200px;" class="container-fluid header a">
    <div class="row">
        <a href="#top"><img src="http://hguochen.com/static/img/tech/css3.png"style="max-width:80px"class="img-responsive"></a>
        <div class="col-xs-6">
            <a href="#scr"><button class="btn btn-primary">ABOUT</button></a>
            <a href="#scr"><button class="btn btn-primary">PORTFOLIO</button></a>
            <a href="#scr"><button class="btn btn-primary">CONTACT</button></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div style="margin-top: 200px;">
{YOUR PAGE CONTENTS HERE.}
</div>
```

See: https://jsfiddle.net/u7ck368y/

Answer (score 0):

I have created fork from codepen.

```
code
```

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mAgEYY

you just need to remove that 13% height from the header.
and also need to put logo within column.

Answer (score 0):

Remove `13%` from your `.header` class. Add `top: 0;` with header class and add `padding top: 115px;` to body.

Answer (score -1):

Add `top:0;` to header and `padding-top:8%;` to body or you can wrap your content in a div and add the padding to it.

That way you can keep using % as height to the header element.